# Cant create account on second node in private chain

Tags: private-blockchain

I have problem with connection of two nodes in private network.
First i am set private nodes on different PCs, and create accounts\mine on it apart. And all been ok.

Next time, i am deleted all database, then create custom genesis file, and initalize this file on both nodes. Then, i am run and connect nodes with addPeer command.
Nodes successfully connecting. On first of them, i am creating accounts and mine, second node start to receiving blocks.

But then, i try to create account on second node, it returns hex addres, but accountsList returns undefined.

Comment: Are you using geth or parity? Which are the command you execute to create an account? Account are not synced across nodes, each node has its own sets of accounts.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So sorry, i am just use wrong command. Its listAccounts, not accountsList.